# How to stop sending multiple mails to single MailId

Tags: java, email, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an email to the user. I have used the javax.mail.* and javax.mail.internet.* packages and successfully sent an email, but the problem is that it is sending multiple emails for a single mail ID. How can I make it send only once?

My code:

```
public void sendEmail(){

     System.out.println("called "+j+" time"); 

     emailIDs.add(emailID);

     to = emailID;

     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session1);

     // Set From: header field of the header.
     try {

         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.

         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));

         // Set Subject: header field

         message.setSubject(notifyName[j]+" "+"Document Alert Mail!");

         // Send the actual HTML message, as big as you like

         message.setContent("<h1>document created on "+createdOn+" is coming to expire</h1>",
                            "text/html" );

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);

         System.out.println("Message Sent Successfully....");
     }

     catch(Exception e){

         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

Comment: The problem is unlikely to be in the `sendEmail` method here. What about the code that calls it?

Comment: To second @Tetrinity, add debugging log statements to see how often your method is called.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide argument in your function. It seems that you have added `emailID` element as many times as you call `sendEmail()` function. Every time you call the function, you should clean your `emailIDs` or you just need to send email to the last element.

Here I send only one recipient:

```
public void sendEmail(String emailID){

 System.out.println("called "+j+" time"); 

 emailIDs.add(emailID);

     to = emailID;

     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session1);

     // Set From: header field of the header.
     try{

     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

     // Set To: header field of the header.

     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                              new InternetAddress(to));

     // Set Subject: header field

     message.setSubject(notifyName[j]+" "+"Document Alert Mail!");

     // Send the actual HTML message, as big as you like

     message.setContent("<h1>document created on "+createdOn+" is coming to expire</h1>",
                        "text/html" );

     // Send message
     Transport.send(message);

     System.out.println("Message Sent Successfully....");
     }

     catch(Exception e){

         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```